# iScroll conflict

Tags: jquery, ipad, iscroll

HTML5 template in Mobile Safari on iPad. Div with iScroll is working fine. Also have a jQuery function contained in if/else statement. That function tests if user is tapping outside of the iScroll div and, if so, fades the iScroll div. 
Problem is, the if/else statement works fine as a test if user is tapping outside of second div on the page but doesn't work as a test if user is tapping outside the iScroll div. Can't figure out why, have tried all div ID's associated with iScroll div in the if/else statment but no good.

Function below:

```
var articleBodyEl = document.getElementById('content');
articleBodyEl.addEventListener("touchend", function() {
var $target = $(event.target);
if ($target.is('ul#article_images') || $target.is('ul#article_images li') || $target.is('div#article')) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    $('#article').fadeToggle('fast');
}
});
```

#article = iScroll div

#article_images = the separate div on the page, testes if user is clicking outside this div works fine.
HTML:

```
<div id="article">
<div id="article_content">
   <div id="scroller">
   <div id="text_1" class="article_text">
    <h4>Wish you were here</h4>
    <p>Sometimes we stumble upon a photograph that requires no words whatsoever. An image that proves the ancient adage that a good picture is worth a thousand words (and probably more, if some of them are small words like ‘if’, ‘it’ and ‘er’). </p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing if/else with the following,

```
if (!$target.is('div#article')) { 
    $('div#article').fadeToggle('fast');
}
```

if content div is parent of iScroll div then you may have to stopPropagation on touchend event of iScroll.